# In Seam what's the difference between injected EntityManager and getEntityManager from EntityHome

Tags: java, jpa, seam

I am testing a Seam application using the needle test API. In my code I am using the getEntityManager() method from EntityHome. When I run the unit tests against an in memory database I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No application context active
at org.jboss.seam.Component.forName(Component.java:1945)
at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2005)
at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1983)
at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1977)
at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1972)
at org.jboss.seam.framework.Controller.getComponentInstance(Controller.java:272)
at org.jboss.seam.framework.PersistenceController.getPersistenceContext(PersistenceController.java:20)
at org.jboss.seam.framework.EntityHome.getEntityManager(EntityHome.java:177)
etc ..
```

I can resolve some of these errors by injecting the EntityManager with

```
@In
EntityManager entityManager;
```

Unfortunately the persist method of `EntityHome` also calls the `getEntityManager`. This means a lot of mocks or rewriting the code somehow. Is there any workaround and why is this exception thrown anyway? I am using Seam 2.2.0 GA by the way.

There is nothing special about the components. They are generated by seam-gen. The test is performed with in memory database - I followed the examples in http://jbosscc-needle.sourceforge.net/jbosscc-needle/1.0/db-util.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In Seam what is the difference **between injected EntityManager and getEntityManager from EntityHome** ?

No one.

When using getEntityManager from EntityHome, Seam will lookup a Seam-managed persistence context named **entityManager**. If you set up your Seam-managed persistence context **with other name than entityManager**, your EntityHome will throw an Excedption.

Here is the default implementation of getEntityMananger in EntityHome

```
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return (EntityMananger) Component.getInstance("entityManager");
}
```

And when using a @In-jected EntityManager, Seam will do as shown above. Both are the same Seam managed persistence context.

Remember Seam performs lookup through @In-jected Component field name. For instance:

```
@In
EntityManager entityManager;
```

Because EntityManager field name is **entityManager**, Seam will perform a hierarchical search by using this name;

[Here](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html%5Fsingle/#persistence.seam-managed-persistence-contexts) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983186/hibernate-entity-manager-factory/1983811#1983811) you can see how to set up a Seam Managed Persistence context.

regards,